# Git: permission denied using SSH key

Tags: git, github

I was working on a github repository using ssh key. I did clone the repo and upload some changes to the repository, but when I tried to upload the changed the second time, I did face an error says:

> sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
>
> git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

What I did afterward was to delete the ssh key and upload a new key but the error persist and I tried upload it with no key on the server but it did not work. How to upload the changed to the same repo?

Comment: Maybe you messed something up with this clone configurations, did you try to clone the project again and check whether it is working with the new key?

Comment: yes, I did check with the new key but it outputs the same error [ line 2 and 3 only of the error ].

Comment: What's the output of `git remote -v`? When you `git push` your changes, can you instead execute `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1 git push ....`? That should give you more output

Comment: @chelmertz git remote -v returns the git url for the repo.  But the git push prints out some numbers and the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to perform just the following steps, without making any extra actions that I didn't mention:

1. Delete all your SSH keys on github (may not be necessary but if all your keys are just other attempts to fix the problem, please remove them)
2. Run in git bash the command `ssh-keygen` (no extra parameters needed), and just keep pressing enter until it finished.
3. Copy the public key from `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` (the whole content of the file).
4. Add new SSH key in github and paste the public key you just copied.
5. Clone your repository again in your computer in new path.

If it still doesn't work, run in git bash:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Then repeat stage 5 again.

Comment: I removed them all and I follow all the steps with no luck. I can't clone that repo. why is that?

Comment: I tried this before your answer, I did make a new repository. and I tried to clone it. But the error still occur. I removed all the keys, so I can try from git using the account password but it didn't work as well.

Comment: Assuming you have already set the public key in github as mentioned above, try to run `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`, then try only to clone again (step5)

Comment: Great! I updated the answer, now you can approve it :)